# Stemming in Apache Solr

Tags: apache, solr, solrj, stemming, porter-stemmer

I'm using Apache Solr for indexing data and I wanted to use the stemming analyzer. I used the 'text_en_splitting' field type given in the solr example schema.xml as it contained the 'PorterStemFilterFactory'. I indexed the data and when I tested in the 'Analysis' page, it shows stemmed results. But when I search, I see that it is not using the stemmed results and hence I get no response. For example, i indexed 'write' but when I searched with 'writing', it gives no response. Need some help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you used the analyzer both at index and query level? If not please use it in both in your schema.xml file.

Comment: Yavar, I've used it at both index and query level.

Comment: Could you share the fieldType description of text_en_splitting?